# "whose" vs "who/that + possessive"

Tags: relative-clauses, whose

> A man **that his** kids want to call 'daddy.'

Apparently this sequence is correct. Would it remain so adding on object pronoun, ...call him 'daddy'?

However, substituting  **whose** for *that* + possessive might demand a resumptive pronoun, [*a man **whose** kids want to call **him** 'Daddy.'*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whose-vs-who-that-possessive.3847977/#post-19666933)

Why is it so?

Comment: I like "A man whose kids want to call Daddy."

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're asking. What you are calling a "correct sentence" is not one. It's not even a sentence. Sentences always have a subject and a finite verb governed by that subject. You don't. Please supply actual sentences not fragments for all your examples so that we can understand where you've gone wrong in your syntactic understanding. Noun phrases? Not sentences.

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question as previously directed before it can be reopened. Is this supposed to be like *A man his kids wanted to call Daddy gave the homily after morning mass every Sunday*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with everything that John Lawler said, but there is something I would like to add (so I will not repeat the things he's already made clear).

Whichever option you choose, the important factor that would determine whether ***him*** is compulsory or not licensed is the direct object of the verb ***call***. The person these kids want to call 'daddy' is ***a man***. So in the relative clause this direct object must be expressed by some kind of pronoun that would replace ***a man***. In the version with ***that***:

> ***a man*** ***that*** his kids want to call 'daddy'

*that his kids want to call 'daddy'* is the relative clause and ***that*** has two functions:

1. it modifies ***man*** as head of the relative clause
2. it also serves as direct object of the verb ***call***

Another pronoun which could replace it is ***whom***:

> We use ***whom*** in formal styles or in writing to refer to people when the person is the object of the verb (of the relative clause). We use ***that*** instead of *who, whom* or *which* in relative clauses to refer to people, animals and things. ***That*** can act as the subject or ***the object of the relative clause***:
>
> - It’s the same cooker ***that*** my mother has. (*that* refers to *the same cooker* and is ***the object*** of *has* in the relative clause). ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns))

So your relative clause *that his kids want to call 'daddy'* already has a direct object: ***that***. To add ***him*** is not grammatical because it would express the same object twice. You cannot say:

> *This man's kids want to call this man him 'daddy'.

Even if ***him*** referred to a different person (to another man, not the father of the kids), **a man that his kids want to call **him** 'daddy'* is still ungrammatical because in this case ***that*** is no longer licensed ( it would modify the subject which is already modified by *his*) and should be replaced together with *his* by the possessive ***whose***.

---

As for the other option, if we replace ***that his*** with ***whose***, we have:

> a man ***whose*** kids want to call 'daddy'

The relative has now become *whose kids want to call 'daddy'* and ***whose*** also has two functions:

1. it heads the relative clause modifying ***a man*** (just like *that* in the first option)
2. it [replaces the possessive determiner ***his***](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/clauses-3.html), modifying ***kids*** which is the *subject* of the relative.

So the verb ***call*** is now left without an object, because as we showed, ***whose*** modifies the subject:

> *a man ***whose*** kids want to call 'daddy'

But ***to call*** is transitive and does require an object, so if we want this NP to be correct, we must add it (*him*):

> a man whose kids want to call ***him*** 'daddy'.

That is not to say that ***whose*** cannot also modify the object of a relative clause (it is just not the case in your example):

> You’ll use the possessive case ***whose*** in those clauses that have their subject and their object already satisfied and don’t need an object of a preposition. Thus:
>
> - The child ***whose*** *homework* the teacher *graded* first received an A. (*whose homework* is the object of *graded*). ([Grammar.com](https://www.grammar.com/who-whom-whose/))

Comment: 1) In _a man whose kids want to call him 'daddy'_, *him* is ambiguous between _a man_ vs. another male, right? http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005022.html

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I am sure the context would clarify that.

Comment: What about the following alternatives? _a man **of whom** the kids want to call (**him**?) daddy_  AND  _a man the kids **of whom** want to call (**him**?) daddy_

Comment: Why complicate things if there is a simpler way to say it? No one would say that. "Of whom" is not so common and and normally, it does not replace genitives but should [follow a quantifier](https://www.grammarbank.com/whose-of-which-of-whom.html). The way you used it, "of whom" would be the equivalent of "whose" and would require "him" as I explained for the variant with "whose".

Answer (score 2):

The sequence

- *a man that his kids want to call 'daddy'*

is not a sentence, but a noun phrase *a man,* modified by a relative clause *that his kids want to call 'daddy'*. It is a grammatical noun phrase, and could be the subject or object of a sentence. e.g,

- *A man that his kids want to call 'daddy' was arrested last night for child abuse.*
- *He told me about a man that his kids want to call 'daddy'.*

If you added a pronoun *him*, though, making the relative clause

- *that his kids want to call him 'daddy'*,

the relative clause wouldn't be grammatical. The reason is because the relative pronoun *that*  **already** refers to *him*, because it's been moved out to the front of the relative clause, as required by the rule of Relative Clause Formation. And you don't want to move it back in because there's no rule that allows it.

If this weren't a relative clause, the *that* would just be a complementizer, with no reference, and it would be grammatical as a tensed complement clause:

- *Frank told me that his kids want to call him 'daddy'.*

But not as a relative clause. That's why "subordinate clause" isn't good enough to distinguish relative from complement clauses, and their different uses of *that*.

Comment: Does substituting **whose** for _that_ + possessive make a resumptive pronoun necessary? _a man whose kids want to call **him** 'Daddy.'_ https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whose-vs-who-that-possessive.3847977/#post-19666933

Comment: The possessive is irrelevant; _a man that kids want to call "daddy"_ works. The distinction is between two kinds of _that_, one relative, one not. _A man whose kids want to call him 'daddy'_ doesn't have a resumptive pronoun; the relative pronoun _whose_ refers to the subject _whose kids_, and not to the object pronoun _him_, which is still required.

Comment: @"**still required**" ?? That is contradictory with OP's "If you added a pronoun **him** in  _that his kids want to call **him** 'daddy',_ the relative clause **wouldn't be grammatical**. _

Comment: If you add a direct object pronoun, the clause can't be interpreted as a relative clause (i.e, the relative clause is ungrammatical). _That_ has to be interpreted as a complementizer and not a relative pronoun if there's already an object NP _him_; if the object NP's missing, then _that_ can refer to it as a relative pronoun. But if _whose kids_ is used, it's the subject and not the object of the relative clause, so the object pronoun would still be required in the phrase _call him 'daddy'_. Got all that?

Comment: What about the following alternatives? _a man **of whom** the kids want to call (**him**?) daddy_  AND  _a man the kids **of whom** want to call (**him**?) daddy_